# AWS Cognito doesn't send verification email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Read through other SO posts, implemented the solutions, and this still seems to be an error.

My issue is simple: I'm using AWS Cognito and requiring email verification for users. However, when I get to this page:

[image]

I don't see the email, even after 2 hours. Steps I've ensured:

1. Enabled email verification in the Cognito console
2. Checked that the user email field is filled out. It is.
3. Enabled a domain name for my app sign up and sign in.
4. Tried resending the code.

I don't believe I'm over the daily quota limit for Amazon Cognito (I haven't configured it with SES), since I haven't gotten verification email today. Does anyone know why this is occuring?

Comment: Checked Spam folder?

Comment: Yes, checked spam folder

Comment: Opening a case with AWS Support seems like a good solution. Since they'll have access to your account, they can exactly pin point where the problem is.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this issue? I am facing a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure it with SES, else vignito cannot send emails directly, you have to configure SES with Cognito.

Comment: Your answer should be detailed, or just add it as a comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).